# Hold (one) by the throat

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I am reading Atlas Shrugged by Ayn Rand. There is a statement by Hank Rearden - 'You concluded that I was the safest person in the world for you to spit on, precisely because I held you by the throat.' 
This phrase is used to connote that the person whom Hank has allowed to be in his house as a freeloader has taken undue advantage of Hank while going to the extent of working against Hank. 
Please explain the meaning of 'held you by the throat'.

Comment: There are many aspects of Atlas Shrugged that don't make sense.

Comment: It appears to be a metaphorical referrence to Hank's feeding of Phillip, though it's not a familliar phrase.

Comment: @HotLicks, maybe that is what it is.